# How to order by multiple columns not creating different groups using Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table which looks like this:

| Name | AltName |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | null |
| Ann | null |
| null | Mark |
| John | null |
| null | Bart |
| Sasha | null |

I want to order by both `Name` and `AltName`. If I do this:

```
Table::orderBy('Name')->orderBy('AltName')->get();
```

This will return the data in this order:
`Ann, John, Sam, Sasha, Bart, Mark`

I don't want it to group the data but instead merge it like this: `Ann, Bart, John, Mark, Sam, Sasha`

How can I achieve this using Laravel eloquent or raw SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want here is a `COALESCE` of some sort, if you want to do it in SQL.

This should do the trick;

```
Table::orderByRaw('COALESCE(Name,AltName)')->get();
```

It shouldn't matter which way around you put `Name` and `AltName` given that your data shows one is always `NULL` if the other value is present.

Comment: Works great! However, if some row contains both values, how do I take `Name` from that row?

Comment: NVM, I think your solution already solves that as it takes Name if it's not null.